# How To Create A Unique List From Multiple Sheets Using Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365, filterxml

I am working on a payroll sheet, and I need to extract **Unique Employee ID** from multiple sheets in the workbook and place them in the same workbook in another sheet.

Although I am able to create a formula, to get those **Unique List** however I am not able to make it **dynamic**, since every month I shall be importing a new sheet in the workbook and that should be taken into consideration, which is not working out with my formula.

I have tried using the `INDIRECT` Function to dynamically refer all the sheets but in vain may be I am doing something wrong here. I know it can be done with **Power Query** but I dont want to change the structure of the database also its possible with **VBA**, but I'm reluctant to it, specifically want to accomplish it using **Excel Formula**.

The below formula which I have used in Master_List Cell **A2**

```
="ID_"&SORT(SUBSTITUTE(UNIQUE(
FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",,Blad1:Blad3!A2:A1000)
,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")),"ID_","")+0)
```

[image: BLAD1]

[image: BLAD2]

[image: BLAD3]

[image: MASTER_List]

I tried using this as `SHEETS` Defined Name within the formula, but it gives **#REF** Error

```
=SUBSTITUTE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),"["&GET.WORKBOOK(16)&"]","")&T(NOW())
```

The above formula, is used for grabbing other sheets data for calculations, tried implementing it within the formula by wrapping it within `INDIRECT` function, but doesn't work, I know why is n't will it possible to make it dynamic or is there any workaround. I hope am able explain. Thank you for the effort and time.

Note: This is a sample data, created for the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on formulae, here is what I did to make this work:

- I created a name formula in the name manager: `SHEETNAME`. It refers to: `=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")`
- Assuming you have at least two sheets (a 'Master' and any other sheets have ID's in column A;

Now I used in `A2` in the masterlist:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(SHEETS()-1,,2),LAMBDA(a,b,TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,a,INDIRECT(INDEX(SHEETNAME,b)&"!A2:A100"))))&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

**Note1:** I assumed you have only got ID's in the range of `A2:A100` to keep it rather simple.

**Note2:** This use of `TEXTJOIN()` can hit it's limits rather quick.

**Note3:** You could try to nest a 2nd `UNIQUE()` that would make sure that each iteration handles as little as records as possible. This would hopefully make sure that the limits of `TEXTJOIN()` aren't hit as quickly.

Comment: Sir, it worked perfectly, like a charm! Really `FILTERXML` is a treat ! So I have 5 sheets until now, and I have to consider the {3,4,5} Sheets hence I edited this part in my workbook `SEQUENCE(SHEETS()-2,,3)` . Also since those ID's are number I have used a `SORT` Function in the beginning as well, I already have `Sheets` Defined do I need to use the one you have given or shall I continue with the one I am using.

Comment: [`SHEETS()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sheets-function-770515eb-e1e8-45ce-8066-b557e5e4b80b) is a native function, not a function you should create yourself @MayukhBhattacharya. So remove that from your name manager.

Comment: Sir that I understood I am telling whether do i need to use another defined name for the `SHEETNAME` since I am already using one defined as `Sheets` --> `=SUBSTITUTE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),"["&GET.WORKBOOK(16)&"]","")&T(NOW())
` and Sir, do you think what I have tried to achieve is valid.

Comment: If it works it's valid. `INDIRECT()` is volatile allready, so using `NOW()` won't make such a negative impact nomore I think.