# Is there a way to add a tab name dynamically to an Excel formula based on another cells content?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column (A) that will only contain values that are also the names of tabs within the same workbook.

Let's say they are fruits: Apple, Banana, Lemon, Orange etc. but new fruits may appear in column A in future, and they will automatically get their own tab named after them.

In column B I want to pick up the value of cell A1 on the appropriate tab depending on which fruit is in column A, so for a row where column A is Apple, I want it to pick up the value of A1 in the Apple tab. If column A is Banana then I want it to pick up the value of cell A1 in the Banana tab etc...

Is it possible to do this in a formula, or should I use VBA to dynamically create a regular formula that specifically references the correct tab name in each row?

Thanks

I haven't tried anything yet as not sure where to start with this!

Comment: `INDIRECT()` is what you need, however other way round is using `VSTACK()` and doing a match few other functions maybe! If sheets is added in future then `Excel Macro 4.0` has a function which will add the new sheet tabs automatically as well. Refer this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71512017/8162520)** solution by @JvdV Sir on how to grab the sheets automatically!